# Why I get errors on my XML file generated with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm creating an xml file with php from an array of values. Everythings work fine until the function saveXml().
When I open the xml I find some error every 16384 characters

My code:

```
$db_results = $this->getValues(array('1','2','3'));
        if( @count($db_results) > 0 ){
            $XML = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><dati></dati>');
            $XML->addAttribute('tipologia', '_tipologia1');
            foreach($db_results as $key => $val){
                $blocco_1 = $XML->addChild('blocco1');
                $blocco_1->addAttribute('blocco1_id',$val['id']);
                $blocco_2 = $blocco_1->addChild('info_blocco2');
                $blocco_2->addChild('id',$val['id_td']);
            }
            if(file_exists($this->_export_dir . 'output.xml')) unlink($this->_export_dir . 'output.xml');
            $XML->saveXML($this->_export_dir . 'output.xml');
        }
```

I can not paste the error in the xml. You can see in the image below
[OUTPUT XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UY18.png)

I try to increase server memory limit but the problem is still here.

Any suggestion are welcome

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

**Show us how you build the XML so we can't help**

Comment: Ok, now you can find the code and the error (I can't copy and paste the error so I insert the image)